# Ansible create directories for each environment

Tags: ansible

Using the below snippet of ansible code, I am trying to create multiple subdirectories as per the variables stored in vars/main.yml. So the goal is for every user per env, I am attempting to create multiple sub folders

Eventually, the folders should be created like

```
/home/testuser1/subdir1
/home/testuser1/subdir2
/home/testuser2/subdir3/subdir4
/home/testuser2/subdir5/subdir6
/home/testuser3/subdir7
/home/testuser3/subdir8
/home/testuser4 - testuser4 will not have any subfolders, so i assume ansible will not take any action
```

Playbook file:

```
---
- hosts: all
user: test
sudo: yes
vars_files:
- defaults/main.yml

tasks:

  - name: Create directories for each env
  file: path="{{ home }}/{{ item.0 }}{{ item.1.name }}/{{item.0.subdir}}" owner="{{ item.0 }}{{ item.1.name }}" group="{{ item.0 }}{{ item.1.name }}" mode=755 state=directory
  with_subelements:
  - "{{ env }}"
  - "{{ userdir }}"
  - "{{ subdirs }}"
```

vars/main.yml

```
env:
- test
- qa

userdir:
- name: user1
  subdir:
  - subdir1
  - subdir2
- name: user2
  subdirs:
  - subdir3/subdir4
  - subdir5/subdir6
- name: user3
  subdirs:
  - subdir7
  - subdir8
- name: user4
  subdirs:
  - []
```

However, after the execution of the playbook, I am getting a strange error. I am sure something is wrong in the above code, but I couldnt move further. Appreciate if some experts can throw some light

```
TASK: [Create directories for each env]         ****************************
fatal: [localhost] => subelements lookup expects a list of two items, first a dict or a list, and second a string

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message  tells, `with_subelements` expects a string, not a var for the 2nd element. The string must be a property in each element of the first dict/list. But more problematic is, a 3rd element is not supported.

The best probably would be to loop only over the users and their directories and make the environments static, because there currently is no solution to have nested loops:

```
- name: Create directories for test env
  file: path="{{ home }}/test{{ item.0.name }}/{{item.1}}" owner="test{{ item.0.name }}" group="test{{ item.0.name }}" mode=755 state=directory
  with_subelements:
  - userdir
  - subdirs

- name: Create directories for qa env
  file: path="{{ home }}/qa{{ item.0.name }}/{{item.1}}" owner="qa{{ item.0.name }}" group="qa{{ item.0.name }}" mode=755 state=directory
  with_subelements:
  - userdir
  - subdirs
```

In Ansible 2.0 it will (again) be possible to have nested loops by using `with_items` together with the `include` statement. Then you will be able to do something like this:

```
- include: create_directories.yml env={{ item }}
  with_items: env
```

And in the file `create_directories.yml` then only one task:

```
- name: Create directories for {{ env }} env
  file: path="{{ home }}/{{ env }}{{ item.0.name }}/{{item.1}}" owner="{{ env }}{{ item.0.name }}" group="{{ env }}{{ item.0.name }}" mode=755 state=directory
  with_subelements:
  - userdir
  - subdirs
```

I don't know when Ansible 2.0 will be released but you could try the code directly from github. They have a [v2_final branch](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/v2_final), but it appears the [devel branch](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel) has more recent code.

Comment: Thanks udondan. I will give it a shot and let u know. However it is little painful as i need to create the loop for almost 15 environments and it can grow.. nut like u said i can revisit when ansible2.0 is released

Comment: Thanks udondan, it worked like a charm.. however i ended up create 20 actions for 20 different environments.. I wish there was a more better solution. I need to get more ansible done..

Comment: It's no big improvement, but you could have 1 task in a separate file instead and then include it 20 times with a parameter.